# AS3: Part of code doesnt get executed

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

So, I need to remove my frog, from a small flash game, after 3 times moving, I'm trying to do this with 'aantalGezwommen' and a function, sadly it doesn't work with the code now.

I can't figure it out, any of you got an idea?

I have included the whole code, so if something else is wrong, please tell :)

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class KikkerOgen extends MovieClip {

        var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 4);
        var geknipperd:int = 0;
        var hoevaakKnipperen:int = 0;
        var aantalGezwommen:int = 0;
        var score:int = 0;

        //boompjes en bosjes
        var object_1:Point = new Point(57,84);
        var object_2:Point = new Point(500,86);
        var object_3:Point = new Point(46,168);
        var object_4:Point = new Point(479,126);
        var object_5:Point = new Point(69,159);
        var object_6:Point = new Point(443,162);
        var object_7:Point = new Point(248,316);
        var object_8:Point = new Point(209,198);
        var object_9:Point = new Point(163,357);
        var object_10:Point = new Point(440,283);

        //constructor
        public function KikkerOgen() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, isClicked);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Knipperen);
            timer.start();
            gotoAndStop(13);
        }

        public function Update (event:Event)
        {
            trace(currentFrame);
        }

        //Score moet bij deze functie omhoog - document class
        public function isClicked (event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }

        //Hier telt hij het aantal keren dat de kikker moet  knipperen
        function Knipperen (event:TimerEvent):void 
        {
            if (event.currentTarget.currentCount >= 2 && geknipperd < 3) {
                geknipperd ++;
                gotoAndPlay(1);
            }

            //Wanneer de kikker 3x geknipperd heeft moet hij naar een nieuwe positie
            if (geknipperd == 3)
            {
                //Selecteer een random positie om heen te zwemmen
                switch(Math.round(Math.random() * 10)) 
                {
                    case 1:
                        x = object_1.x;
                        y = object_1.y;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        x = object_2.x;
                        y = object_2.y;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        x = object_3.x;
                        y = object_3.y;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        x = object_4.x;
                        y = object_4.y;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        x = object_5.x;
                        y = object_5.y;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        x = object_6.x;
                        y = object_6.y;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        x = object_7.x;
                        y = object_7.y;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        x = object_8.x;
                        y = object_8.y;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        x = object_9.x;
                        y = object_9.y;
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        x = object_10.x;
                        y = object_10.y;
                        break;
                }
                trace("posX:"+x);
                trace("posY:"+y);
                //Reset de timmer, het knipperen en laat hem opnieuw tellen om te verplaatsen.
                geknipperd = 0;
                trace(geknipperd);

                //Tel hoevaak het kikkertje verplaatst is om de kikker bij 3x van stage te verwijderen. 
                if (aantalGezwommen < 3) {
                    aantalGezwommen++;
                }

                timer.reset();
                timer.start();
            }
        }

        //Wanneer de kikker 3x is verplaats verwijder hem uit het spel
        function removeKikker ()
        {
            if (aantalGezwommen == 3)
            {
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Apologies for the Dutch notes, things I need to remember :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in your code you are calling the removeKikker function. For a function to run it has to be called.

Comment: Thanks, have been working way too long on this so couldn't find the issue anymore.